# Execute some code in "DidEnterRigon"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3, monitoring, region

I want to execute some code when the user enter rigon

first: I want to enter database and get some information 
then: I want to display Alert.

Is it possible ? or I can't execute any kind of code at 'background'? 
and if there is any alternative way to do so

thank you

Comment: What platform are you writing for?  How do you define a "region"?

Comment: I'm working on xcode "objective c"
well, I used Region monitoring as apple produce it.
and I used "didEnterRegion" method which triggered by locationmanager 
and I put "UIAlertView" and it shows whenever I entered the region.
but I'm wondering if I can execute some code ?

Comment: Ah...since you're using `UIAlertView` that would make the platform iOS rather than OS X.  (They both use Xcode and Objective-C.)

Comment: yeah sorry I'm developing iphone application. So, what do you think! can I execute some codes?